# d3/javascript filter data according to input

Tags: javascript, d3.js, filter

Sorry if my question maybe very basic but I've taught myself and it's hard to proceed without knowing fundementals in javascript

To make my question simple, let's say I have data looking like below:

```
country, value1, value2, 
US, 100, 50,
UK, 30, 20,
Germany, 40, 30,
France, 20, 10
```

I'd like to make a dropbox where value1 and value2 are options. So, when user select value1 option in the dropbox, then visualisation only for value1 appears.

So I wrote some psudo code like below filtering data according to the input.

```
function update() {
var selected = menu.property("value");
data.filter((d) => return d3.keys(d[0]) === selected; )}
```

Dose it sound okay? or there is something to be fixed?

In addition, after filtering the data, I need some more manipulations on data. So I need country attribution as well as either value1 or value2. Does anyone know how to remain the country attribution when filtering?

Thanks,

Comment: This might be overkill for what you want to achieve, but take a look at [crossfilter](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter). This library is designed to do the exact thing you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking you don't need to filter, you can just select which property of the data you wish to visualize:

First, let's make the select menu based on the columns you have, d3.csv will produce an array that looks like:

```
var data = [
  {"country":"US", "value1": 100, "value2": 50},
  {"country":"UK", "value1": 30, "value2": 20},
  {"country":"Germany", "value1": 40, "value2": 30},
  {"country":"France", "value1": 20, "value2": 10}
];
```

Now we can get the columns, if using d3.csv we can access the columns with `data.columns`. Since we don't want the country as an option, just the values, we can slice it off with `data.columns.slice(1)`. *I just use a javascript object in my snippets, so I use `d3.keys(data[0]).slice(1)` to achieve the same effect*.

Now we can create a drop down based on how many values we have in our dataset with:

```
// Create a select element
var select = d3.select("body")
  .append("select")
  .on("change", function() {
     // Log value it is changed to:
     console.log(this.value);
  })

// Add an initial option:
select.append("option")
  .html("Select Value:")

// Add the columns as options:
var options = select.selectAll(null)
  .data(values)
  .enter()
  .append("option")
  .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

Which gives us this:

```js
var data = [
  {"country":"US", "value1": 100, "value2": 50},
  {"country":"UK", "value1": 30, "value2": 20},
  {"country":"Germany", "value1": 40, "value2": 30},
  {"country":"France", "value1": 20, "value2": 10}
];

// Get the columns. 
var values = d3.keys(data[0])
  .slice(1);

// Create a select element
var select = d3.select("body")
  .append("select")
  .on("change", function() {
     console.log(this.value);
  })

// Add an initial option:
select.append("option")
  .html("Select Value:")

// Add the options:
var options = select.selectAll(null)
  .data(values)
  .enter()
  .append("option")
  .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Now we can use that on change function to pass a property name to an update function (*either as a parameter or, as I do below, by taking advantage of the fact that the the callback function's `this` is the element the event is triggered on*). That update function will take that property and use it to modify the visualization:

For example:

```
select.on("change", update)

function update() {
   var property = this.value; // this is the element.

   // .... scale modification eg: scale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[property]; }))
   // .... enter/update/exit cycle       

   // Use property to shape visualization, eg:
   updateSelection.attr("property", function(d) { return scale(d[property]); })
```

If you need to refine the scales depending on property or change the type of visualization, you can do it in this function. And of course, you still have access to all of the data's properties here so you could still use other properties to modify the visualization (say in a tooltip).

Below I've created a simple visualization, changing the drop down updates the graph (simply though, no scale modification, though to accommodate a selection of the initial option (which doesn't represent a property of the data) I've used `d[property] || 0` when scaling values, which removes the visualization gracefully).

```js
var data = [
  {"country":"US", "value1": 100, "value2": 50},
  {"country":"UK", "value1": 30, "value2": 20},
  {"country":"Germany", "value1": 40, "value2": 30},
  {"country":"France", "value1": 20, "value2": 10}
];

// Get the columns. 
var values = d3.keys(data[0])
  .slice(1);

// Create a select element
var select = d3.select("body")
  .append("select")
  .on("change", update)

// Add an initial option:
select.append("option")
  .html("Select Value:")

// Add the options:
var options = select.selectAll(null)
  .data(values)
  .enter()
  .append("option")
  .text(function(d) { return d; });
  

// Create an SVG
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 400);
  
// Spice it up with some scales:
var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.country; }))
  .range([0,500])
  
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0,100])
  .range([150,0])
  
// Specify an Update function to create and update visualization elements: 
function update() {
  var value = this.value;
  var bars = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data);
    
  bars.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.country); })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("y", 150)
    .attr("height",0)
    .merge(bars)    
    .transition()
    .attr("height", function(d) { return 150 - y(d[value] || 0); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[value] || 0); });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew! It is exactly what I wanted to know. Cheers!